# Google drive user rate limit exceeded for exceedingly small rate

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google drive api calls (google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.Copy and google.apps.drive.v3.DrivePermissions.Create) from within a Google cloud function at an exceedingly low rate - 2 calls every week. There are no retries in my code - if it fails, it gets logged and the run ends. Last run the first call returned a `userRateLimitExceeded` error. I've checked the quotas in Google drive api settings in my project and they're 12000 per minute and 12000 per minute per user. I don't see how I could possibly exceed that. Are there other causes for that error? What else should I check?